# Function for getting URLs

Tags: python, url

This is a simple Python program I wrote.  I hope some one could help me optimize this program. If you found any bad habits, please tell me.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib2

def GetURLs(srcURL=""):

    if srcURL == "":
        return -1

    Content = urllib2.urlopen(srcURL, None, 6)
    oneLine = Content.readline()
    while oneLine:
        print oneLine
        oneLine = Content.readline()
    Content.close()
    return 0

GetURLs("http://www.baidu.com")
```

Comment: For starters, dont start your method name with capital letters.Try getURLS() instead of GetURLs same goes for Content (begins with capital letter). In general class names start with capital letters not method or variable names. And I am not sure what are you trying to do with while online: routine. Try to read this book
http://www.amazon.com/Code-Complete-Practical-Handbook-Construction/dp/0735619670 for best practices in programming.

Comment: yes, maybe I should follow your advice.Thx

Comment: You should really follow PEP 8: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: One piece of 'non-pythonic' code is the guard clause. While often good practice in other languages in python exceptions are light weight and recommended practice. So rather than checking if the url=='' just pass it the urllib2 and deal with the exception using try: except:

Comment: @DavidHall: In all honesty, I wouldn't call guard clauses 'non-pythonic', and furthermore I wouldn't call throwing exceptions as being Pythonic, necessarily. It's more of a matter of preference, one of which has a distinct (but insignificant) performance advantage. Here's the [case for guard clauses](http://blog.mafr.de/2009/06/12/a-case-for-guard-clauses/), although, granted, it does not discuss Python directly. Above all, though, if you're working on an existing project, maintaining consistency with the existing convention should be the number one priority.

Answer (score 16):

You asked for comments on coding style, so here goes:

- It's [Python style](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to use CapitalizedNames for classes and lower_case_names for functions, methods and variables.
- Functions should have docstrings that describe their arguments and what they do.
- Names starting with "get" are normally used for functions that return the value they get. Your function *prints* the content at the URL, so it would be better to call it something like `print_url`.
- The value of 6 for the `timeout` argument to [`urlopen`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) seems arbitrary. It would be better either to leave this out (the caller can always use [`socket.setdefaulttimeout`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.setdefaulttimeout) if they need to set a timeout), or to allow the caller to pass it as a keyword argument.
- You can pass the `timeout` argument as a keyword argument to avoid having to specify `None` for the `data` argument.
- Having a default value for `srcURL` is pointless, especially since it's an invalid value! Omit this.
- The return value is useless: it's -1 if the argument was an empty string, or 0 if it wasn't. If the caller needs to know this, they can look at the argument they are about to supply. (Or they can catch the `ValueError` that `urlopen` raises if passed an empty string.)
- The `Content` object does not get closed if the `readline` function raises an error. You can ensure that it gets closed by using Python's `try: ... finally: ...` statement. (Or [`contextlib.closing`](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) if you prefer.)

Applying all of these improvements, plus the [one suggested by Lev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9646592/68063), yields this function:

```
def print_url(url, timeout=6):
    """
    Print the content at the URL `url` (but time out after `timeout` seconds).
    """
    content = urllib2.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout)
    try:
        for line in content:
            print line
    finally:
        content.close()
```

Comment: Can't you just use a `with`-block to handle closing? I.e. never mind `contextlib.closing`; doesn't the object returned by `urllib2.urlopen` already implement the context-manager protocol?

Comment: @Karl: try it and see!

Answer (score 5):

You can shorten your code by optimizing iteration over the lines. `urlopen()` returns a file-like object that allows direct iteration:

```
content = urllib2.urlopen(srcURL, None, 6)
for line in content:
    print line

content.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is a bit more idiomatic:

```
def getURLs(srcURL=""):
    if not srcURL:
        return -1
    content = urllib2.urlopen(srcURL, None, 6)
    try:
        for oneLine in content:
            print oneLine
    finally:
        content.close()
    return 0
```

Notice that by convention, function names start with lower-case. I simplified the test condition at the beginning, and more importantly, the iteration can be written in a simpler way. And as a good practice, resources should be closed in a `finally` block.